# Problems configuring connection / censored

Tags: bridge, network-configuration

Im having problems figuring out how to configure my connection properly. Ive tried bridges and proxies. Currently in the USA, I dont know if that helps. Here's the logs with and without provided obfs4 bridge.

==============WITHOUT BRIDGE ============================================================

5/12/2017 21:58:44 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:58:44 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:58:44 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:58:44 PM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/12/2017 21:58:45 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

5/12/2017 21:58:45 PM.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

5/12/2017 21:58:45 PM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection

5/12/2017 21:58:45 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus 
consensus

5/12/2017 21:58:45 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus

5/12/2017 21:58:46 PM.400 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time(DIRSERV:128.31.0.34:9101): It seems that our clock is behind by 4 days, 4 hours, 53 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings.

5/12/2017 21:58:50 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

5/12/2017 21:58:50 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:58:50 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/12/2017 21:58:50 PM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.

==========WITH PROVIDED OBFS4 BRIDGE ===========================================

5/12/2017 21:48:31 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:49:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:49:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:49:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:49:01 PM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
5/12/2017 21:49:07 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server

5/12/2017 21:49:07 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server

5/12/2017 21:49:08 PM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 198.245.60.50:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:29 PM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:4304 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:29 PM.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.11:16488 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:42 PM.400 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 192.95.36.142:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:45 PM.500 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 85.17.30.79:443 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:50 PM.300 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 83.212.101.3:50002 ("general SOCKS server failure")

5/12/2017 21:49:51 PM.100 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running 
bridges

5/12/2017 21:50:02 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

5/12/2017 21:50:02 PM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or 
accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

5/12/2017 21:50:02 PM.400 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150

Comment: `5/12/2017 21:58:46 PM.400 [WARN] Received directory with skewed time(DIRSERV:128.31.0.34:9101): It seems that our clock is behind by 4 days, 4 hours, 53 minutes, or that theirs is ahead. Tor requires an accurate clock to work: please check your time, timezone, and date settings.` missed that